# Boostrap modal goes dark when clicked on Hyperlink

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal, servicenow

I have a web page developed in Service Portal (ServiceNow Application) with  Angularjs 1.x and Bootstrap 3. The bootstrap modal contains some data and hyperlink to the full page(shown below). The expected behaviour is when user clicks on hyperlink it should take him to different page. But, browser takes him to different page and shows the information faded/dark window.

HTML Code:

```
 <!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"> Potential Indicator </h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form name="indicatorModal" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label  col-sm-4">Indicator #: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                <label class="labeldata" id="indicatorId"></label>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label  col-sm-4">Indicator Status: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                <label class="labeldata" id="indicatorStatus"></label>
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label  col-sm-4">Indicator Type: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                <label class="labeldata" id="indicatorType"></label>
            </div>
             <!-- <p class="form-group"><label>Indicator Type: </label> <label class="labeldata" id="indicatorType"> </label></p> -->
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Urgency Ranking: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                <label class="labeldata" id="urgencyRanking"></label>
            </div>
                 <!-- <p><label>Urgency Ranking:  </label> <label class="labeldata" id="urgencyRanking"></label></p> -->
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Completed Enrich Count:  </label>
              <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                <label class="labeldata" id="completedEnrichCount"></label>
            </div>
                 <!--<p><label>Completed Enrich Count:  </label> <label class="labeldata" id="completedEnrichCount"></label></p> -->
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Enrich Start Timestamp:  </label>
              <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                <label class="labeldata" id="enrichStartTimestamp"></label>
            </div>
                     <!--<p><label>Enrich Start Timestamp:  </label> <label class="labeldata" id="enrichStartTimestamp"></label></p> -->
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
               <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Enrich End Timestamp:  </label>
              <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                <label class="labeldata" id="enrichEndTimestamp"></label>
            </div>
                 <!--   <p><label>Enrich End Timestamp:  </label> <label class="labeldata" id="enrichEndTimestamp"></label></p> -->
              </div>

             <div class="form-group">
               <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Indicator Data : </label>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">     
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="indicatorText" ng-readonly="true"> </textarea>
               </div>
             </div>

             <br/>
             <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="" id="indicatorLink"> Click here for More information</a>
             </div>
        </form>
      </div> 
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>  
</div>
```

Angular JS Code:

```
(function()
{
    "use strict";
    var app=angular.module('indicatorModal',[]);
    app.controller('incidentSummaryCtrl',['$scope',function($scope)
    {
        $scope.passSysId=function(indicatorSysId,indicatorType)
        {
            var ipIndicatorsData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('ipIndicatorsData'));
            var domainIndicatorsData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('domainIndicatorsData'));
            var hashCodeIndicatorsData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('hashCodeIndicatorsData'));
            if(indicatorType == 'IP Address')
                {
                    for(var indicator in ipIndicatorsData )
                        {
                            if(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].sysId == indicatorSysId)
                                {
                                    jQuery("#indicatorId").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorId);
                                    jQuery("#indicatorStatus").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorStatus);
                                    jQuery("#indicatorType").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorType);
                                    jQuery("#urgencyRanking").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].urgencyRanking);
                                    jQuery("#completedEnrichCount").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].completedEnrichCount);
                                    jQuery("#enrichStartTimestamp").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].enrichStartTimestamp);
                                    jQuery("#enrichEndTimestamp").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].enrichEndTimestamp);
                                    jQuery("#indicatorText").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorText); 
                                    $("#indicatorLink").attr("href", "haloportal/?id=potential_indicator_summary&indicator_id="+indicatorSysId);
                                }
                        }
                }
            else if(indicatorType == 'Full Qualified Domain Name (FQDN)')
                {
                    for(var indicator in domainIndicatorsData )
                        {
                            if(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].sysId == indicatorSysId)
                                {
                                    jQuery("#indicatorId").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorId);
                                    jQuery("#indicatorStatus").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorStatus);
                                    jQuery("#indicatorType").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorType);
                                    jQuery("#urgencyRanking").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].urgencyRanking);
                                    jQuery("#completedEnrichCount").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].completedEnrichCount);
                                    jQuery("#enrichStartTimestamp").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].enrichStartTimestamp);
                                    jQuery("#enrichEndTimestamp").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].enrichEndTimestamp);
                                    jQuery("#indicatorText").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorText); 
                                    $("#indicatorLink").attr("href", "/haloportal/?id=potential_indicator_summary&indicator_id="+indicatorSysId);
                                }
                        }
                }
            else if(indicatorType == 'Hash Code')
                {
                    for(var indicator in hashCodeIndicatorsData )
                        {
                            if(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].sysId == indicatorSysId)
                                {
                                    jQuery("#indicatorId").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorId);
                                    jQuery("#indicatorStatus").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorStatus);
                                    jQuery("#indicatorType").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorType);
                                    jQuery("#urgencyRanking").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].urgencyRanking);
                                    jQuery("#completedEnrichCount").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].completedEnrichCount);
                                    jQuery("#enrichStartTimestamp").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].enrichStartTimestamp);
                                    jQuery("#enrichEndTimestamp").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].enrichEndTimestamp);
                                    jQuery("#indicatorText").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorText); 
                                    $("#indicatorLink").attr("href", "haloportal/?id=potential_indicator_summary&indicator_id="+indicatorSysId);
                                }
                        }

                }


        };
    }]);

})();
```

[image: First Window]
[image: Second Window]

Comment: This is because the modal backdrop is still present in the HTML even after the route change. You can remove the backdrop with the following in route change ` $('body').removeClass('modal-open'); $('.modal-backdrop').remove();`

Comment: Pete,
You are the life saver. Can you write this in answer, so that I can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Okay! Updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the modal backdrop is still present in the HTML even after the route change. You can remove the backdrop with the following in route change.

```
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Add this too if required `$('div.modal-dialog').remove();`

I'm not sure whether this is the correct way of solving this problem; but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').removeClass('modal-open').end().$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```